# How to fix you need to enable javascript to run this app in react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[image]I am getting error  you need to enable javascript to run this app. when I run using nom start.

I have tried to change browser settings. but didn't work please see screenshots that I have attached.

```
class AuthPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="auth-form">
                <div className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor="email">E-Main</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-actions">
                    <button type="button">Switch To SIGN UP</button>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to attach the screenshots.

Comment: Sorry!!, now added

Comment: I don't see any errors in your screenshots. The left panel is the rendered page, and the top right panel is the HTML from the rendered page. The noscript HTML is there so that visitors to the site with JS disabled would see that message. You are not seeing that message on the left, so you have JS enabled. Also, if JS was disabled then you wouldn't be able to see your navbar. If there are any errors, then they'll have shown up in the Console tab.

Comment: I found issue which was not in this class it was in App.js class where I mistakely put "Component" instead of "component". Thank you and sorry for this inconvenience.